# Why is Google Analytics not recording clicks when used in Cycle 2?

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, jquery-cycle2

I am using [Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) for a news ticker having 3 server side generated articles. I am attempting to use the `onClick` syntax for the `ga.js` version of analytics. As far as I can tell, I've done it correctly, but I have been consistently getting zero clicks for two weeks, which makes me think there may be a problem (I should mention that *I've* clicked on it to test it with no results, as it has occurred to me that it's possible that no one clicked it). Here's what I have:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
     data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
     data-cycle-fx="fade" 
     data-cycle-timeout="6000"
     data-cycle-slides="> div"
     >
    <div><a href="<? echo $url1; ?>" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ReadThisNow', 'Click', '<? echo $title1; ?>']);"><? echo $title1; ?></a></div>

    <div><a href="<? echo $url2; ?>" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ReadThisNow', 'Click', '<? echo $title2; ?>']);"><? echo $title2; ?></a></div>

    <div><a href="<? echo $url3; ?>" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ReadThisNow', 'Click', '<? echo $title3; ?>']);"><? echo $title3; ?></a></div>


</div>
```

I left the PHP echo statements in since although I don't think they are the cause, it's possible they are. There is no html being output, only URL's and titles.

I've been using analytics right along with other projects, so I suspect there is some problem with using it in Cycle 2, but I've found nothing documenting it. What is going wrong here?

Comment: What happen if you disable Cycle? Does it work? If yes,, then cycle probably removes event-listener or stop eventPropagation. Try to asset event-listener in console and see what happen.

Comment: Is your data-cycle-slides attribute value correct, as you've pasted?

Comment: @JakubKriz It works in other places on the same page that are not in the cycle, yes. I'll have to get back to you regarding results, as it takes a day for them to be displayed. There is an error in console when I click on it. I'll have to try to see if that's related.

Comment: @nyuen Yes, that is correct as I pasted.

Comment: @Chris send that error messages please

Comment: @JakubKriz Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Then it specifies the line number where the onClick is. Not an awful lot to go on.

Comment: @Chris : Is this part correct? data-cycle-slides="> div"
     >

Comment: That's what I asked as well, as it looks odd to me. Is that a valid value for a data-attribute?

Comment: @JakubKriz (also nyuen) I agree it looks odd. But according to this [documentation page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php), it is correct.

Comment: @Chris ok, then it have to be in onclick part. Please, open your website, turn on Firebug or whatever similar (F12) and send us result of your PHP sequence [<div><a href="<? echo $url1; ?>" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ReadThisNow', 'Click', '<? echo $title1; ?>']);"><? echo $title1; ?></a></div>] in HTML tab. There have to be some stupid error.

Comment: Check the output and put special attention to single vs double quotes appearances. Another question would be, When you are talking about 'zero clicks' are you talking about 0 click data in the 'event' report or 'conversion' report?

Comment: @titico Well, I feel dumb now. The titles contain single quotes that I didn't change to html safe codes. I've been trying so hard to figure it out, and it ends up being something so silly. But to answer your other question, 'zero clicks' was refering to the click data in the 'event' report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output and put special attention to single vs double quotes appearances